# C++ - Reverse function in a template class stack implementation

Tags: c++, function, stack, reverse

this is my stack implementation using template with a struct type node and a class type stack:

---

Stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class t>
struct node{
    t data;
    node<t>* next;
};

template <class t>
class stack
{
public:
    stack();
    ~stack();
    bool isEmpty(){ return (top_ptr=NULL);};
    void push(const t&);
    void pop();
    t top() const;
    void reverse();
    void clear();
    void print();
private:
    node<t>* top_ptr;
};

template <class t>
stack<t>::stack()
{
    top_ptr=NULL;
}

template <class t>
stack<t>::~stack()
{
    while(top_ptr != NULL) pop();
}

template <class t>
void stack<t>::push(const t& source)
{
    node<t>* new_node = new node<t>;
    new_node->data = source;
    new_node->next = top_ptr;
    top_ptr = new_node;
    cout << "Inserito!" << endl;
}

template <class t>
void stack<t>::pop()
{
    node<t>* remove = top_ptr;
    top_ptr = top_ptr->next;
    delete remove;
    cout << "Rimosso!" << endl;
}

template <class t>
t stack<t>::top() const
{
    assert(top_ptr != NULL);
    return top_ptr->data;
}

template <class t>
void stack<t>::clear()
{
    node<t>* temp;
    while(top_ptr != NULL)
    {
        temp = top_ptr;
        top_ptr = top_ptr->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    cout << "Clear completato!" << endl;
}

template <class t>
void stack<t>::reverse()
{
    stack<t> new_stack;
    while(top_ptr != NULL)
    {
        new_stack.push(top_ptr->data);
        pop();
    }
    cout << "Reverse completato!" << endl;
}

template <class t>
void stack<t>::print()
{
    node<t>* ptr = top_ptr;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout << " " << ptr->data << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

#endif /* STACK_H_ */
```

---

And this is the main.cpp:

```
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{
    stack<int> stackino;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) stackino.push(i);
    stackino.pop();
    cout << "top(): " << stackino.top() << endl;
    stackino.print();
    cout << "Invoco clear()" << endl;
    stackino.clear();
    cout << "Stackino dopo clear():" << endl;
    stackino.print();
    cout << "Invoco reverse()" << endl;
    stackino.reverse();
    cout << "Stackino dopo reverse()" << endl;
    stackino.print();

    cout << "FINE!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

The problem is reverse() that causes a crash of the program, I guess "top_ptr = new_stack.top_ptr" is wrong but it makes compile and execute, but crashes. Can someone help me correct this?

Comment: Your `isEmpty` function ain't right, for a start...

Comment: To expand on the above comment `top_ptr=NULL` will set `top_ptr` to `NULL` (BAD) and return `false` every time, change it to `==`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Runs fine under Clang, GCC, and VC++. Must be undefined behavior or somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @djanthony93 What do you mean by "crash?" Does it actually segfault or something to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the issue.  Let me know if I am interpreting this wrong.
When you do `top_ptr = new_stack.top_ptr`, you're putting the temporary stack's top as yours.
The problem is, when that temporary stack gets destructed, it still has the same `top_ptr`, and deletes all the memory that was associated with it.  That leaves your real stack with a bad `top_ptr`.

I would suggest trying:

```
top_ptr = new_stack.top_ptr;
new_stack.top_ptr = NULL;
```

So that it doesn't clear away your stack, and leave you with a bad pointer.
Hope that works?

Comment: It compiles but when I try to print() my stack, it print nothing :(

Comment: According to your Main() method, aren't you completely clearing your stack before doing the reverse?